# How to properly decouple MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm rather new to web development all together. I'm trying to get a node.js/express/mongo project off the ground. I'm coming from a C/C++ background, and the module organization paradigms seem a little strange to me.

Currently, in my `server.js`, I create, connect, and initialize my mongoDB object using mongoose, then pass around this object query, insert ect on it. Doesn't seem like something I should be doing inside `server.js`.

Is the proper way to loosely couple Mongo from my project by creating a separate module (ex. database) where I do all the initialization, options, ect, and return a mongodb instance through this new module?

I've never undertaken a project of this size (or type) before, and just don't know how to best organize everything.. 
Any advice from those people much more experienced than me would be appreciated

Comment: Use layering and dependency injection. That is, have a separate module for data access that's receives a MongoDB object as an init parameter, and a separate module handling the setup of this object and passing it to data access, then handing the data access stuff to your controllers.

Comment: It's certainly not a definitive answer (and, given how opinionated Node programmers tend to be, I suspect that a definitive answer may not exist), but there are interesting discussions on this topic at the following links: https://gist.github.com/viatropos/1398757, http://rycole.com/2013/01/28/organizing-nodejs-express.html, and http://onoffswitch.net/separation-concerns-node-js/

Comment: This [github repo](https://github.com/linnovate/mean) has a good example of how organize your MEAN application, although you'll not be using AngularJS.

Comment: @millimoose Thanks for the response. Do you mind elaborating in an answer? I'm a little confused

Comment: @gone This is mostly a Cliff's Notes version of a pattern that's used pervasively in .NET or Java. (But is applicable anywhere.) I'd suggest searching around for "data access layer" and "dependency injection" and seeing how those concepts translate to your environment. Dependency injection is a popular way by which you achieve the sort of decoupling you describe - the idea is that every component has no business knowing how to create other components it depends on. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with Express or MongoDB specifically so I can't provide a response tailored to your setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many ways to do it. Here's some ideas.

Yes, you'll want to have a routing/handlers setup of some kind so that different modules have the ability to call different services and/or decouple.

Below is a fairly standard node.js / express structure:

```
├── server.js
├── config
│   ├── development
│   ├── production
│   └── staging
├── handlers
│   ├── customers.js
│   └── stores.js
├── node_modules
│   ├── assert
│   ├── ejs
│   ├── express
│   ├── forever
│   ├── mongodb
│   └── mongoskin
├── package.json
├── README.md
```

then in server.js, you can import your handlers like so:

```
// import route handlers
var customers = require('./handlers/customers'),
    stores = require('./handlers/stores');
```

and then inside your handlers, you'll be able to declare functions:

```
exports.addCustomer = function(req, res) {
    // ....
};
```

which in server.js you can use for routing:

```
app.post('/customers/add/:id, metrics.addCustomer);
```

so then you've got a basic framework. Just defining the database connections outside of the `exports.XXX` functions in the handler files is fine because those functions will have access, but not anything in `server.js` so you won't pollute your namespace.

```
var url = config.user +":"
        + config.pass +"@"
        + config.host +"/"
        + config.database;

var mongo = require('mongoskin').db(url);
```

where you might load the `config` object from a JSON file.

hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Looks like a good idea for handling different requests. But what would I do with something like mongo, or a different module I use that would be needed by multiple handlers?

Comment: create it in `server.js`. then you can actually give arguments to the `require()` method by doing something like: `var customers = require('./handlers/customers')(mongo_instance)` and then get access to it there. there are of course many ways to do this but this is a direct way.